# Job title for employee between junior and middleweight in full stack developer role

Tags: promotion, developer, title, tech-industry

Our Junior Full Stack Developer has began enquires for a promotion. I'm not sure if they're ready for the full title just yet (simply dropping the Junior portion). I like this to be a goal to strives towards. They've improved a lot and have worked incredibly hard so I'd like to reward them with a recommendation for promotion.

I know they'd like to get the "Junior" name out of the title. Is there a snappier industry term for a lower-middle-weight-full-stack-dev?

Thanks.

Comment: No, there isn't. If you'd like help finding a title, whether according to the industry standard or not, that's [probably off topic for this site](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/416/is-there-a-title-for-that) and I'd recommend [chat].

Comment: Welterweight-Fully-Stacked-Deviant

Comment: One point.  Jack, if - incredibly - your employee (in software!) wants **a title rather than money** then ........  (A) you're the luckiest team lead on Earth  :)   ... and ...  (B) give them a title like "Executive Chief Senior Managing Global Lead of Architecture, Hiring, Planning, Engineering and Design" !!

Comment: I once saw a guy get the title "Configuration Manager" three months in on his first job after graduation...

Comment: LOL @JuhaUntinen   I have had the title "Manifestor".    :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literal answer to your question is "No, there's no such title."

It's worth noting that, in general (not always but in general) titles are non-existent or mean almost nothing in the hurly-burly of software.  It's all about money, really.

FWIW: to me just "Developer" signifies what you are implying. For folks in to titles, once you get above that you start adding things like "lead", "architect" and so on.  So one solution is to escalate the more senior titles, and leave "Developer" meaning a basic developer!

Comment: I agree with "Developer," unless the OP wants to institute numbered bands like Developer I, Developer II, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While "Junior Fullstack Developer" is his title, the developer can still have roles like "Responsible for Code Reviews for this part of the code", or "Responsible for training of new hires". There are tons of examples.

In my opinion, Titles like Junior, Senior, etc. are only useful for describing job qualifications. I've seen one company where this title also had correlation with pay levels.

Being promoted usually means "Having a different job description that is usually accompanied with more responsibility and may have an increase in pay".

Promotions are tricky. No discussion about promotion can be done in vacuum. What is your company's promotion policy? Who else might deserve a promotion that may be ahead in line? etc.

Motivation, on the other hand - that's the name of the game. You want this developer to feel motivated and we understand now that it can be done by improving the job title. My suggestion is rather than changing their title, focus on increasing their responsibilities and empowering them. Make them in charge of something, and you can easily add that as part of his job description.

Answer (score -2):

Defining the titles, job descriptions, and pay ranges for a hierarchy of positions is usually done before starting to fill those positions. They are also done in a purposeful manor to make sure they fit with the philosophy, structure and financials of the business. They also should be done to fit other positions to make sure there is consistency.

If you want to have only two steps then they should be: X and Senior X
If you want three steps then they should be Junior X, X and Senior X.

In cases where more steps are needed I have worked with companies that used names such a Engineer 1, Engineer 2, Engineer 3...